# SpringBoot2 Failed to auto-configure a DataSource: 'spring.datasource.url' is not specified and no embedded datasource could be auto-configured

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My project use springBoot2,And it does not need to connect database,But springboot auto configurate datasource and throw an exception when starting project.
I have add execute,but it does not work

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class
})
@ImportResource("classpath:spring-config-platform.xml")
public class JunoIotPlatformBoot1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(JunoIotPlatformBoot1Application.class);
        Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("server.port",8091);
        app.setDefaultProperties(map);
        app.run(args);
    }
```

Because I megerate old spring project(xml) to springboot project,so ImportResource is necessary.
log is:

```
    2018-04-16 16:19:01,141][restartedMain][WARN][org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:557)] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

.....

    [2018-04-16 16:19:01,221][restartedMain][INFO][org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:180)] Stopping service [Tomcat]
    [2018-04-16 16:19:01,259][restartedMain][ERROR][org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter.report(LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter.java:42)] 

    ***************************
    APPLICATION FAILED TO START
    ***************************

    Description:

    Failed to auto-configure a DataSource: 'spring.datasource.url' is not specified and no embedded datasource could be auto-configured.

    Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


    Action:

    Consider the following:
        If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
        If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Comment: And 'spring.datasource.url' is in your application.properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your build script, looks like you have some not needed starter there (something that is starts with `spring-boot-starter-data-...`)

Comment: I was missing
```
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It can also happen when JPA dependency is set in the pom.xml with no database dependency.

To me, initializing the project with JPA was no enough - I needed to add the relevant database, e.g. **H2**.

To fix that, add your database dependency to the pom, e.g. for **H2**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```